# Zeppelin Cluster Mode not working on spark 1.2 Ambari, Hortonworks CLuster

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, ambari, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to deploy a cluster and run some sample Spark/scala code on it and while everything works fine when I use zeppelin in standalone mode with default parameters, I cannot get it working in cluster mode.
I tried to manually create spark cluster using *spark-class* and *start-master* standard shell-files in spark and then passed *spark://..* URL to Zeppelin, however after running the code I keep getting different exotic errors (like java sys.process._ library is missing) and after a while spark workers' status changes into DEAD in Spark MasterUI

I also tried to put *yarn-client* instead of a spark-URL in zeppelin spark.home variable but it did not work producing similar errors.

Could you please help me deploy zeppelin on Ambari cluster and/or hint what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Zeppelin integration with Ambari, please using this [ambari-zeppelin-service](https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/ambari-zeppelin-service) from Hortonworks.

It is well documented and works in cluster mode too.